# How to get working Landscape and Portrait layout total pages count in a single report using jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, report

I've multiple reports( one is Portrait and other one is Landscape).I compile 'em separately and merge them in a single report.

Since I'm  generating the reports and then merging it, current page number and total pages is 
not available... so my report shows only first report page count and not including second report page count

How to overcome this...any suggestions?

Comment: No..its not grails plugin

Answer (score 0):

Implement a parameter in the second report "$P{offset}". When the first report is generated, count the pages and pass the count to the parameter of the second report.

Then use an expression like "$P{offset} + $P{PAGE_NUMBER}" in the second report.

Comment: If i do that it works partially but first report doesn't have the total number of pages(first report + second report)..so how to overcome that...